# How to make my machine think a given dns for xyz.com points to localhost

Tags: linux, dns

I want to be able to enter xyz.com into my browser but get essentialy some site running on my local apache. The catch is I don't feel like setting up a dns server to do the job. Is there a workaround? Some quick way how to do that in linux? (dont need a redirect, for lack of better words: the site must think its running on xyz.com)
Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/10438)

Answer (score 4):

Of course: `/etc/hosts`

Example:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

Comment: Had no doubts, but it works in this way because of nsswitch.conf common configuration: no magic ;) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html